# How to set label.text with NSString as soon as new view loaded, NSString value is set in class method

Tags: iphone

I want to set label on my new view (which I am loading on selection of table row) to variable NSString value,
here is what I am doing

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath          
 {

    int selected_row = [indexPath row];
    SingleTon *index_instance = [SingleTon sharedInstanceIndex];
    [index_instance setIndex:selected_row];
    selected_row = [index_instance getIndex:selected_row]; 
    NSLog(@"Selected row %d", selected_row);
    [SelecetionViewController uploadthecontent:selected_row];
    [self presentModalViewController:selection_controller animated:YES];
}
```

.h file contains

```
NSString *rest_name;
IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;   
//Some class methods declared
```

.m file contains

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

    [super viewDidLoad];  
    lbl.text = rest_name;   
}

//class method
+ (void)uploadthecontent:(int)data  
{  
    SelecetionViewController *controller = [[SelecetionViewController alloc] init];  
    [controller labelset:data];    //calls labelset method which set rest_name to some value
    [controller release];  

}

-(void)labelset:(int)data{

    [rest_name release];
    SingleTon *indexinstance = [SingleTon sharedInstanceIndex];
    SingleTon *rnameinstace = [SingleTon sharedInstance1];
    //SingleTon *baddrinstance = [SingleTon sharedInstance2];
    NSMutableArray *selected_rname;
    //eNSMutableArray *selected_baddr;
    int i = [indexinstance getIndex:data];
    selected_rname = [rnameinstace getRName:selected_rname];
    NSString * rname = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:selected_rname] objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Retaurant name : %@",rname);
    //lbl.text = rest_name;
    rest_name = [[NSString alloc] init];
    rest_name = rname;
    NSLog(@"I am here : %@",rest_name);
    //[rest_name retain];
}

//rest_name is what I am trying to access and set as label
```

Comment: Your setting an ivar (name) in a class method? Are you sure you're reading from the same variable? Check the address of name when you set it and when you read it.

Comment: show your code that sets the value of your `name` ivar

Comment: I am using class methods because I have no idea how to perform some actions before the view loads, so before loading the new view I am calling class method of that view to do some actions and store some variable for me from my SingleTon class. If someone can tell me better  way of dealing with it, is most welcome, because if I do what I am doing in my viewdidLoad method application get halt.

Comment: include the code for your tableViewController's `didSelectRow:atIndex:` method. Generally, you initialize the new view, set ivar values needed by the view then present the new view in this method

Comment: have added the didSelectRow:atIndex method also.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your outlet might not be connected ?

Comment: It is connected, because I can see my buttons on it. and on clicking button I can change by label to some hard coded text.

Comment: Show me the code that you click on the button and set the label, please

Comment: lbl.text = name; //it is not working, name is my NSString which i am populating in my instance method.

Answer (score 0):

You probably failed to connect your `lbl` Oulet in Interface Builder. Select your View Controller in interface builder, look at the connections section and connect `lbl` to the `UILabel` object in the View.

Comment: When i use NSLog("Here %@",rest_name); in viewdidLaod I am getting warning "warning: passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' from incompatible pointer type"

Comment: NSLog is showing the rest_name : null, I have updated the question to show what I am populating in rest_name in my class method

Comment: But the name and the rest_name is different, you are talking about 2 different problems. Show me the code you init the name

Answer (score 0):

The question is over a year old but since I just found it while I searched for a solution I thought I might answer it. At least what was my problem.

I just had the exact same behavior. The mistake I did was that I forgot to connect the Outlets (UITextFields) I have created to my File's Owner in Interface Builder.